# Expression to target the last column in a matrix column group

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

Is it possible to write an expression that targets only the last column in an SSRS 2005 matrix column group to, for example, make the font bold or set a border?

Answer (score 1):

You can try an expression like this :

```
-IIF(RunningValue(Fields!Col.Value,CountDistinct,"RowGroup") = 
    Countdistinct(Fields!Col.Value,"RowGroup"), Case1, Case 2)
```

Here RunningValue Statement gives you count for each col group instance starting from 1 till last value of col group and Countdistinct will give total distinct count of col group values. So effectively I am checking if last value of runningValue = Total Count value, i.e., my last instance of Column Group.

Answer (score 0):

Add a [Row_Number()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms186734%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) to your dataset and partition it the same way as your column group and use an Order By Desc so that the last record for each grouping in your dataset result will have a row number of 1. You can then set Row_Number = 1 expressions for elements in the report matrix to make the column hidden, the font bold etc.